# URL path for multi-language

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have the existing web app (Spring MVC). I need to make i18n for all the contents.

The requirement for managing the language is to use language code directly in the URL. So for existing URL:

```
http://example.com/product1
```

I will need to create N *virtual* URLs like

```
http://example.com/EN/product1
http://example.com/FR/product1
```

I'm investigating the different option to achieve this. One dirty solution I found is to use the interceptor which will check the language code in the URL, removing the language code, to make a valid URL and set the Redirect. But it's so ugly...

What is the best approach to implement this?

Comment: This is very broad. And will depend on a lot of things... and might be due to opinions so you might be closed off

Comment: Use a url rewriting mechanism which translates the new url's into something you understand at the backend (the old URLs).

Comment: I do not think that a well done filter based solution is so ugly, because it keep the i18n url handling in one spot and does not spread it everey where in the application . Of course it should do an internal forward instead of an redirect and needs to manipluate the constructed URLs (from the jsp) too.

Comment: this issue is being considered by the Core Spring team to support this natively - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25791

Answer (score 1):

There will be multiple ways to do this and they will depend somewhat on your application scale.

Personally I can quickly think of

- Assign multiple URL-mappings to the Spring mvc-dispatcher:

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/EN/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/FR/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/GR/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```
- If you have RAM to spare, you could simply deploy the application multiple times - once for each language context you want to support. This would allow replicating heavy-used languages on multiple servers and have low-volume ones otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, Jan. Sounds interesting, I will experiment with this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all the possible ways to implement this will be ugly. That's just because the requirement does not make any sense (you're implementing the language switcher anti-pattern, aren't you?).

So much for my rant, the easiest way would be to use "classic" Spring MessageSources and capture the locale in your controller. Since I have no idea how you implemented your controllers, what view technology you're using and so on, let's say:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SomeController {

  @RequestMapping(value="{lang}/product1" method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public getProduct(@PathVariable String lang) {
    Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(lang);
    LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale);

    return "product1";
  }
}
```

This will set the locale and a view will be using them to resolve messages (provided it's internationalized).

The only problem with this example is, I haven't tested it and I am not quite sure it will work :) It's likely that you would have to re-organize the parameters, or to make matters worse use one controller for everything (which would be a terrible solution).

Comment: unfortunately, there are too many controllers to modify and this solution will be hard to maintain while adding new route... Any way, thank you for your help

Comment: It would be a bit less afford when you add the language to the Controller-CLASS RequestMapping and use a interceptor to obtain and set the locale.

Comment: @Yev to not copy this code around all the controllers you could create interceptor or servlet filter.